# I am a NON US resident but I have a SSN and I formed an LLC in Wyoming. Do I need an EIN or I can use my SSN?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, limited-liability-company, ein, ssn

I'm a NON US resident but I have a SSN and I formed an LLC in Wyoming. Do I have to apply for EIN or I can use my SSN? I am the only member of an LLC.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register for an EIN from the IRS before you start cutting paychecks and withholding taxes for your employees. In the US there is a layer of Federal requirements on top of the state-level requirements, and this is one of those cases: there’s not going to be a Wyoming-specific EIN but instead an EIN from the IRS. See irs.gov for the online form.

Comment: Does it change the situation that it's a single member LLC?

Answer (score 0):

> [I]f the SMLLC doesn't have any employees, the business owner can use
> his or her social security number rather than obtain a different tax
> identification number.

At the same time, the [article](https://www.upcounsel.com/sole-proprietorship-vs-single-member-llc) says that you must always treat the single-member LLC as its own entity, not as an alter ego. I ask, wouldn't using your SSN for the LLC violate that principle?